Conditional probability - choosing $2$ students from classes: one with $15$ girls + $15$ boys and another one with $20$ girls + $10$ boys.
Class $1A$ has $15$ girls and $15$ boys, class $1B$ has $20$ girls and $10$ boys. We draw a class (each choice is equally likely) and then two different students from that class.

Calculate the probability that there is at least one boy among the students drawn.

My idea was to calculate the probability of an opposite event (choosing only girls) and then deduct that probability from $1$.
$A =$  there is at least one boy among the students drawn.
$$\mathbb{P}(A) = 1 - \left( \frac{1}{2} \frac{{{15}\choose{2}}}{{{30}\choose{2}}} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{{{20}\choose{2}}}{{{30}\choose{2}}} \right)$$

Assume that there is at least one boy among the students drawn. What is the probability that $1A$ class was drawn?

$B =$ there is at least one boy among the students drawn. I calculate that the same way as in previous subsection.
$A =$ class $1A$ was drawn.
The idea to calculate $\mathbb{P} (A \cap B)$ is similar to $\mathbb{P}(B)$ - I calculate the probability of an opposite event (choosing class $1B$ or choosing only girls) and then deduct that probability from $1$
$$\mathbb{P}(A|B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)} = \frac{ 1 - \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{{{15}\choose{2}}}{{{30}\choose{2}}} \right) }{1 - \left( \frac{1}{2} \frac{{{15}\choose{2}}}{{{30}\choose{2}}} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{{{20}\choose{2}}}{{{30}\choose{2}}} \right)}$$

Suppose there is at least one boy among the students drawn. What is the probability that a girl and a boy were drawn?

$B =$ there is at least one boy among the students drawn.
$A =$ a girl and a boy were drawn.
The idea to calculate $\mathbb{P} (A \cap B)$ is simple - we need to have $1$ girl and $1$ boy and we can get that event in one of $2$ classes.
$$\mathbb{P}(A|B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)} = \frac{\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{15 \cdot 15}{30\cdot 29} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{20 \cdot 10}{30 \cdot 29}}{1 - \left( \frac{1}{2} \frac{{{15}\choose{2}}}{{{30}\choose{2}}} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{{{20}\choose{2}}}{{{30}\choose{2}}} \right)}$$
Does it look correct?

You forgot to divide by the total possible outcomes for P(A) expression. It's a negative value according to your formula

@Gwen thank you for help, you are right, I forgot about those in each case. I have edited my question. Does it look correct now?

You know what. I'm not that great in combinatorics. The first one was quite understandable. Even if your second answer is correct, I don't think myself to be a good verifier. I don't know why this post didn't get any other users. Did you ask your mentor/teacher etc about this?
